# How to have nested classes/forms in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.net and coming from a Ruby on Rails background. I have 3 tables in question they are Booking, Customer and Contact (contact being customer contact details). Basically what i want to do is have one form which will create all of the objects required in one go, so if i create a booking it also creates a customer and their contact details. I am familiar with this process in Rails which is accepts nested attributes for. I'd appreciate any pointers for a similar solution in ASP.net

Comment: I flagged your question as being too broad. This is a big subject and you need to really narrow it down to what your core issue is. Does it not work to just simply create a form that gathers the appropriate details from the user and then run three insert statements to update your database with the appropriate information? Or use an ORM mapper such as Entity Framework to create 3 entities and save them?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning Entity Framework as an ORM for this application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878